# Ubuntu 14.04 with Nvidia 840M Crashes After Opening Video in VLC

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

Each time I opened any video using VLC Media Player, the system went into a total deadlock or crash. I had to hard-shut down the computer. Afterwards I unchecked the setting "Preferences > Video > Accelerated Video Output (Overlay)" in VLC. The problem haven't occur but video performance has worsened. Also, I experience the same problem when making a video call in Skype. System crashes as soon as camera video starts to display.

I suppose the problem occurs because of graphics card driver. Because a video codec or player crash cannot cause whole system failure.

I'm using 14.04 and I have hybrid graphics cards. Discrete one is Nvidia 840M.
I don't know how to check my graphics card driver is properly installed.

Need help. Thank you.

Comment: I runned 'sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration'. Result is 'configuration: driver=i915 latency=0' for Intel integrated, 'configuration: latency=0' for nVidia graphics card. Does that mean there is no driver installed for nVidia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video driver is not installed. Proprietary driver from Ubuntu 14.04 repository does not support this adapter. I suggest upgrading kernel and installing the driver this way. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Then reboot. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Reboot again.

Comment: Hello again.  After installing proprietary drivers, screen freezing has emerged. Screen freezes especially when using Firefox browser with a lot of tabs. I recover the user interface by switching terminal mode and then immediately graphical mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1 and Ctrl + Alt + F7). Does this problem stem from Nvidia driver or X Window System?

Comment: @user6994 It is better to ask a new question and give there output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`.